# How to create an OSGI Library of that has custom controls that reference the Extension Library?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have created a simple OSGI Library that I have added a custom control from one of my databases. The Custom Control uses controls from the Extension Library. I can't figure out how to tell the new library to use the Extension Library. Either the IBM one or Openntf.

Comment: Please clarify your question; for example, what is a 'custom control' in this context? Is it a product-specific item?

Comment: As an example I have created a custom control that I have created that I use for entering People/Groups/Roles into a Names field in a document. My ccPickNames has a number of custom Properties that are set when the custom Control is added to an XPage. These custom properties determine if the user is allowed a single name or multiple names, also determines if they can select a role or a group, etc. My ccPickNames includes the Extension Library NamePicker.

Comment: So I have created a Library that I want to make into an OSGI Library to deliver with my product, and so it can be used in multiple applications. The problem is that when I add ccPickNames to the Library it generates an error because it does not have access to the Extension Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology is a little confusing. By "Custom Control" I'm assuming you mean "Component" as a custom control contains XSP Markup inside it (i.e. XML). But to address your issue, in the MANIFEST.MF file of your plugin, on the dependencies tab in the required plug-ins. Add com.ibm.xsp.extlib as a dependency. While you're there you'll probably also need to add:

- com.ibm.xsp.designer
- com.ibm.xsp.domino
- com.ibm.icu

Looking at your previous question... I mirror Tim's suggestion of getting the XSP Starter Kit as that contains examples of custom components, resource providers, phase listeners, JS Library inclusion, etc.